# Set default cms page for product in Shopware 6.4

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to change the default CMS page product when you create a new product and not assign a template yet. And I had a custom cms page duplicate from the default one.
I followed this thread from before https://shopwarecommunity.slack.com/archives/C011VFQT7GB/p1690365867570799

I already ran `bin/console system:config:set core.cms.default_product_cms_page XXX`.
After that I ran `bin/console system:config:get core.cms.default_product_cms_page` and it changed.

But still, when I reloaded the new product it still used the default CMS page of shopware (the one that can't be changed)

After that I checked in database system_config with configuration_key is core.cms.default_product_cms_page, and I saw the value did not change, So I changed it also. But then still the same result.

It's really weird. Has anyone done this before? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this ADR](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/adr/2022-04-06-add-default-cms-layouts-to-products-and-categories.md) the default layout will be used as a fallback, unless a product is assigned a specific layout. However the use of the fallback is [behind a feature flag](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Content/Product/Subscriber/ProductSubscriber.php#L96) for the next major release `6.6`, as it is considered a breaking change. A hard-coded layout will still be used as a fallback until the release of the next major version. So even when you change the default layout now, already created products will not be affected and new products still need to be assigned a specific layout. The easiest way to change the layout for all existing products seems to be via a direct database query.

```sql
UPDATE product SET cms_page_id = UNHEX(UPPER('01896e2807c071f8b244dac3e78f2d70'));
```